Snowflake Alert not executing Condition
I'm trying to create a Snowflake alert for queries running for more than 1 minutes. However, the alert I've created seems to be triggering as true for every run, even when I deliberately run a query that exceeds the time threshold.
As an experiment, I even added a SQL statement 'Call System$wait(500)' to ensure the condition is met, but the alert continues to show condition_false for all runs. If I run the same query manually then this Query returns the records. I have tried all the conditions but it does not work except the case when I use SELECT 1 as Condition.
Any insights on why this might be happening? I can confirm the Alert Schedule is working fine.
CREATE OR REPLACE ALERT MY_ALERT
  WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
  SCHEDULE = '2 MINUTE'
  IF (EXISTS ( 
     SELECT *
      FROM TABLE(SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())
      WHERE EXECUTION_STATUS = 'RUNNING'
        AND start_time < current_timestamp() - INTERVAL '1 MINUTES'
       )
    )
  THEN
      -- doing something
      SELECT 1
   END;

ALTER ALERT MY_ALERT resume;

.

My immediate suspicion is that it's a privilege issue or context issue. If the privilege requirements aren't met, in some cases you'll not get a failure. You'll not see the rows for the that require the privilege instead. Please refer to these usage notes: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history#usage-notes
